# Comparing one month in DAX with differents months

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I hope you can assist me in this matter, I have to compare one month as a baseline between the next months, this my formula in DAX PowerBI as the baseline:

***BaseLine Formula***
DQ_BASELINE_DEC =
CALCULATE([TotalNumError],
FILTER (Dates,
YEAR(Dates[Date]) = 2020 && MONTH(Dates[Date]) = 12
)
)

***The next formula for the current year and month:***
TotalNumError_YTD = CALCULATE(SUM(DQ_CUS[NumErrors]),
FILTER(Dates,
YEAR(Dates[Date]) = 2021 && MONTH(Dates[Date]) in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}
)
)

the expected output with percentage is this but I don’t get the next percentages comparing December 2020 with the rest of months:

[image]

***DAX Formula  for getting %***
DQ_%_TEST = DIVIDE([TotalNumError],[DQ_BASELINE_DEC],BLANK())

Can anybody help me in this matter?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For calculating the baseline try using some of the time intelligence functions. In your case SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR should do the trick. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/sameperiodlastyear-function-dax